# Applet window closing

Tags: java, applet

I have  a login applet which takes username and pwd.It has submit window after clicking submit button,internally username and pwd are checked by server and if the info is valid then  a new window is displayed.
I want the login applet to be closed when submit or any-other button is clicked.
I tried using `System.exit(0)` which stops entire application.
Kindly tell me how to close only applet window.

Comment: *"I tried using `System.exit(0)` which stops entire application."*  By 'application' DYM the browser?  Never call `System.exit(0)` in an applet, instead do something like `showDocument("ByeBe.html")`.  An applet should not be closing the window or tab in which it resides.

Comment: i tried showDocument but it didnt worked...applet window didnt closed and it didnt redirected to specified url

Comment: is there any other way to close only applet window?iam using japplet...